# Strange bug in Fallout 1

Tags: macos, fallout

I'm playing a GOG version of Fallout 1 and am experiencing a strange bug. The problem occurs when I'm using a stimpack from a quick action menu, it is being used, but disappears from the menu, so I'm only able to use only one stimpack without accessing the inventory. Anyone knows how to fix this?

UPD: forgot to mention that my OS is MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: I haven't played Fallout 1 in years, but I don't think it's a bug. You don't hold whole stack of stimpacks (or any other one-use items) in quick action menu, just one.

Comment: Well, maybe I've always been playing a buggy version of fallout 1 and 2, since it's the first time it doesn't act like a stack :)